# Best practice for setting MySQL replication over WAN

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to use MySQL replication over WAN for backup purpose.

What are the Best practice for ensuring data consistency, and without too much manual interruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it

I would set up simple MySQL replication over a VPN.

The replication process is quite simple, and you could use a utility like OpenVPN.

This is the simplest and easy way I can think of.

This is a tutorial to set up replication in Fedora 10 (the process is going to be pretty much the same) http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-mysql-database-replication-on-fedora-10

Here's how to set up an OpenVPN 
http://openmaniak.com/openvpn.php

You can use a MySQL Replication Monitor to ensure the process is running as it should.

Answer (score 0):

are you just looking for backups or an actual mysql server running elsewhere?

DKNuckles answer is right on the $money...

However -If it is just backups - a simple backup script (free) might work well for you

http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/
A great script from wipe_out@lycos.co.uk which takes daily, weekly and monthly backups of your MySQL databases using mysqldump. Features - Backup mutiple databases - Single backup file or to a seperate file for each DB - Compress backup files - Backup remote servers - E-mail logs and much more...

keep in mind  - 
**RUNNING BACKUPS IS A GREAT IDEA**  :-)  as issues such as mysql data loss from human error, programming error etc would replicate across the vpn / cluster as well